# Question on object assignment in Python - Linked list node example

Tags: python, linked-list, variable-assignment

Given a singly linked list implementation and instantiation:

```py
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.next = next
        self.val = val

head = ListNode(1)
head.next = ListNode(2)
head.next.next = ListNode(3)
head.next.next.next = ListNode(4)
```

After the following operations:

```
current_node = head
current_node = current_node.next
current_node.next = current_node.next.next
```

the resulting linked lists are  2->4 for `current_node`, and 1->2->4 for `head`. The result for `current_node` makes sense to me, but I am confused as to why the result of `head` is changed at all.  After these 3 operations, I had expected `head` to be equal to what it was originally (1->2->3->4) as there aren't any operations made directly to `head`. However, if the operations were this instead:

```
current_node = head
current_node.next = current_node.next.next
```

I do expect `head` to be modified as well to 1->3->4, as both `current_node` and `head` reference the same memory address. In contrast, in the first example, after the second line the reassigned, `current_node` no longer references the same memory address as `head`. My understanding is that whatever happens to this reassigned `current_node` shouldn't be related to `head` anymore (which apparently isn't the case). Can someone please explain what is happening with `head` in the first example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Via `head` you can reach the other nodes. If one of those nodes get's their `next` attribute adapted, this will be "visible" when starting from `head`.

It may help to visualise what is happening in the first case. We start out with a linked list that can be pictured as follows:

```
head
  │
┌─┴─────────┐   ┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ val: 1    │   │ val: 2    │   │ val: 3    │   │ val: 4    │
│ next: ────────┤ next: ────────┤ next: ────────┤ next: None│
└───────────┘   └───────────┘   └───────────┘   └───────────┘
```

Then `current_node` is defined with `current_node = head`, which results in this state:

```
head
  │
┌─┴─────────┐   ┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ val: 1    │   │ val: 2    │   │ val: 3    │   │ val: 4    │
│ next: ────────┤ next: ────────┤ next: ────────┤ next: None│
└─┬─────────┘   └───────────┘   └───────────┘   └───────────┘
  │
current_node
```

Then `current_node = current_node.next` makes it reference the second node:

```
head
  │
┌─┴─────────┐   ┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ val: 1    │   │ val: 2    │   │ val: 3    │   │ val: 4    │
│ next: ────────┤ next: ────────┤ next: ────────┤ next: None│
└───────────┘   └─┬─────────┘   └───────────┘   └───────────┘
                  │
                 current_node
```

Then comes the *mutation* of the list with `current_node.next = current_node.next.next`:

```
head
  │
┌─┴─────────┐   ┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ val: 1    │   │ val: 2    │   │ val: 3    │   │ val: 4    │
│ next: ────────┤ next: ──────┐ │ next: ────────┤ next: None│
└───────────┘   └─┬─────────┘ │ └───────────┘   └─┬─────────┘
                  │           └───────────────────┘
                 current_node
```

As you can see, it doesn't matter whether you access the node with value 2 via `head` or via `current_node`: that node has **one** `next` attribute and it will always be that one that is followed when traversing the list. Unless you create a **new** node with value 2, there is no way that this node could somehow say that its successor is the node with 3 when you arrive there starting from `head`, while at the same time it would say its successor is the node with 4 when your traverse it from `current_node`.

Comment: thanks! the visualization really helps. did you mean current_node instead of current_head?

Comment: Yes, it should be `current_node`. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

At first operation

```
current_node = head
current_node = current_node.next
current_node.next = current_node.next.next
```

At first line  head
and current_node have the same memory address but after executing the second line now the head.next and current_node have the same memory address
However in

```
current_node = head
current_node.next = current_node.next.next
```

The head and current_node have the same memory address that's mean any change that would happen in current_node value will cause the same for head
If you don't want that start searching for deep coping and shallow copy

Answer (score 0):

`head` and `current_node` are always the same node(object) in your example. I modified the code so that you can easily print out the list from the current object to the end. This might make experimenting/understanding the code a bit easier. But the explanation of @trincot is very good (in my opinion).

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.next = next
        self.val = val

    def __str__(self):
        msg = ''
        tmpNode = self
        while tmpNode:
            msg += f'->{tmpNode.val}'
            tmpNode = tmpNode.next
        return msg


def createSingleLinkedList():
    print('\n# init single linked list')
    head = ListNode(1)
    print(f'head_a{head}')
    head.next = ListNode(2)
    print(f'head_b{head}')
    head.next.next = ListNode(3)
    print(f'head_c{head}')
    head.next.next.next = ListNode(4)
    print(f'head_d{head}')
    return head


head = createSingleLinkedList()
print('# modify single linked list 1')
current_node = head
print(f'head_a{head}')
print(f'current_node_a{head}')
current_node = current_node.next
print(f'head_b{head}')
print(f'current_node_b{head}')
current_node.next = current_node.next.next
print(f'head_c{head}')
print(f'current_node_c{head}')

head = createSingleLinkedList()
print('# modify single linked list 2')
current_node = head
print(f'head_a{head}')
print(f'current_node_a{head}')
current_node.next = current_node.next.next
print(f'head_b{head}')
print(f'current_node_b{head}')
```

output:

```
# init single linked list
head_a->1
head_b->1->2
head_c->1->2->3
head_d->1->2->3->4
# modify single linked list 1
head_a->1->2->3->4
current_node_a->1->2->3->4
head_b->1->2->3->4
current_node_b->1->2->3->4
head_c->1->2->4
current_node_c->1->2->4

# init single linked list
head_a->1
head_b->1->2
head_c->1->2->3
head_d->1->2->3->4
# modify single linked list 2
head_a->1->2->3->4
current_node_a->1->2->3->4
head_b->1->3->4
current_node_b->1->3->4
```